# Qt Creator: creating a installer encapsulating 3rd party libraries

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'm trying to build an installer for a Qt-based application. It depends on some Qt libraries, which is not a problem to build an installer, but it also depends on 3rd party libraries: OpenCV, SuiteSparse, FFTW, and some other libraries coded by me.

Is it possible to create a "one-click" installer with Qt Creator that handles both Qt libraries and these too? Or should I create a script that installs the dependencies and integrate it somehow in the Qt Creator? If so, how can I do that?

I'd like to pass most of the responsibility to Qt because this application should be installable in both OSX (in which I'm developing) and Windows, and I wanted to avoid maintaining two codebases if possible.

Comment: Have you looked at the QT Installer Framework?  I've used it to create a one-click installer for Windows including my application, QT dependencies, and other dependencies, but I haven't tried it on OSX.  The gist is that you create a directory structure and a set of XML files to describe your package, and pass it all to QTIFW to create the installer.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I'm struggling to indicate it how to install 3rd party libraries. It only installs QT libraries by default using that framework...